# Ubuntu 18.04 with Multi-touch screen can't single click

Tags: ubuntu, gnu-screen, touch-screen, multi-touch

The problem I have is that my touchscreen registers 2-3 mouse clicks per second when I tap the screen. It continues registering clicks if you hold your finger down. Rather than producing a single touch_down event, it produces a touch_down and touch_up event every ~250ms, so a single click is near impossible.

The touch display is called "[Clicktouch CT_MultiTouch](https://clicktouch.eu/product/)"

I've tried the [libinput](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/) and [evdev](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/evdev.4.html) drivers, but both produce the same behavior.

I've tested the system with a resistive touch screen and it seems to work as I expect. Holding the screen produces a single click, a long press produces right click, etc.

Is there any way to reduce the polling rate of the touch screen or enable a single click so you can press and hold the screen for a single click?

EDIT:
lshw produces the following output

product: RUGGED GTX1050 (Default string)
06/15/2018
RUGGED GTX1050
SPO COMM

Comment: why did you tag this with the "touch" tag. The touch tag is not applicable to your question. Please remove the touch tag.

Comment: Please run `sudo lshw | grep product | head -n1 && sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name && sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer` and paste the result into your question after clicking [edit]. Also please put two space characters after each end of line before you press Enter so what you post formats well onscreen.  Please do not click on Add Comment as new comments can shove old comments off screen; your information about your PC and installation should all go in the Question so we can all see your findings.